# Travis-ci unit test integration failed on iOS keychain

Tags: ios, unit-testing, keychain, travis-ci

I am currently using travis-ci to run builds/unit tests on every github checkins I make for my iOS project.  One of my unit test deals with iOS keychain store, and locally when I run the unit tests, they all pass.

However, on my travis-ci server, it fails with the following error:

```
Aug  6 23:01:31 itako16044.miso xctest[2160] <Error>:  SecOSStatusWith error:[-25291] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.xpc error 3 - <connection: 0x5a8f430> { name = com.apple.securityd, listener = false, pid = 0, euid = 4294967295, egid = 4294967295, asid = 4294967295 }: Connection invalid)
```

I am a n00b when it comes to travis-ci, and some google searches did not yield anything useful.  Is there something I am missing?  How can I set up travis such that I can write things into the keychain store for iOS (it looks like I cannot access keychain store)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xctool? I was having the same problem, but I managed to fix it by using **xcodebuild** instead. My **travis.yml** looks like this:

```
language: objective-c
before_script:
- brew update
- brew install xctool && brew cleanup xctool
script:
- cd NitroKeychain
- xcodebuild -project NitroKeychain.xcodeproj -scheme NitroKeychain -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch)' test
```

It looks like xctool is having some issue accessing the keychain.

Anyway, you can see my project travis.yml and its settings here: https://github.com/danielalves/NitroKeychain